# Spark code takes too long to run

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I have a page of code that takes hours to run and I was hoping for no more than a few minutes. I watched the console while it ran and it appears to be especially hung up on this section

```
def getListComponents(p):
    pair = []
    for i in range(len(p)):
        pair.append((i, p[i]))
    return pair

def addPoints(p1, p2):
    summedPoint = []
    for i in range(len(p1)):
        summedPoint.append(p1[i] + p2[i])
    return summedPoint

for i in range(len(newCentroids)): # len(newCentroids) = 4
    (cnumerator
        .append(wTmx.map(lambda p: getListComponents(p))
        .map(lambda  p: p[i])
        .reduceByKey(lambda p1, p2 : addPoints(p1, p2))))
```

I have read that increasing the memory might help and I've tried anywhere from 2gs to 4gs, but saw no improvement.

```
--executor-memory=3g
```

I have also read that changing the default parallelism can help, setting 2-3 per machine being ideal (I am running a cluster of three)

```
--default-parallelism=9
```

but this has had no effect.

So now I am assuming the problem is in my apparent inability to write efficient code. Is there a way for me to change this code to do the same thing (the entire program works as expected), but take much less time?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I did not know that. But, yes, I'm looking to shave an hour or more off of runtime. :(

Comment: It will be difficult to get an answer to this question without more context. What is `p`, `p1`, `p2`? What is `cnumerator`? What is the code doing?

Comment: Could you put it in some context? What is the content of `wTmx`?  There more elegant ways to do it but there is nothing terribly wrong at first glance.

Comment: @dodell @zero323 Thanks for the feedback. I'd be happy to provide more information. `wTmx` is a list of single-element lists (e.g., [[[1.234], [2.345], [3.456], [4.567]], [[5.678],[6.789],[7.890], ... `p` is each element of this list (the four single-element lists). `cnumerator` is just a list that collects the results of the operation for each i.

Comment: Do you know the desired output of `cnumerator`?

Comment: @dodell Yes, I believe each element of `cnumerator` is just a number (float).

Comment: @MattCremeens No, wTmx is not a list, it appears to be a pyspark RDD. That is a useful thing to know

Comment: @dodell I'm sorry I confused my terminology. I hope the confusion didn't cause too much mispent energy.

Comment: @MattCremeens. Base on your description so far it `cnumerator` will a list of RDDs. Do I understand correctly that you're trying to sum vectors element wise?

Comment: @dodell and @zero323 the `cnumerator` elements are key-value pairs in the form of `[(0, [6453544.453454)]` if that helps. I am summing the list elements by key and storing each result in a list, `cnumerator`.